# Enabling text input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to enable text input using JavaScript. This is my function

```
function enableD()
{
document.getElementById("DeleteI").setAttribute("disabled", false);
}
```

Html is like this

```
<button type="submit" class="Blue_Button" id="DelB" onclick="enableD()">Delete</button>

<input type="hidden" disabled value="DeleteSnack" name="command" id="DeleteI"/>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("DeleteI").disabled = false;
```

Comment: Indeed, setting disabled attribute, whatever the value, disables the input. You have to entirely remove attribute, which can be done using the syntax above.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**.removeAttribute()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.removeAttribute)

```
document.getElementById("DeleteI").removeAttribute("disabled");
```